# Cannot get an image from API

Tags: image, api, flutter

i create an flutter application connected with (API), everything work good, and i can fetch all data from my API, but with image, i encounter a problem, in flutter i get the right URL for image from API, i try it and it is work good when i just paste the URL like this everything work good, and image displayed in mobile:

```
 leading: Image.network("http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload/0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png"),
```

this url (http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload/0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png), i fetch it from API ..... by this code:

```
getCategories() async {
    var res = await http.get("http://192.168.43.106:3000/cat");
    if(res.statusCode == 200){
        var jsonObject = json.decode(res.body);
        print(jsonObject['result']);
        return jsonObject['result'];
    }
```

and then :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    getCategories();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getCategories(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.data != null){
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Image.network(snapshot.data[index]['img']),/*
  }
```

but as you see when i make

```
leading: Image.network(snapshot.data[index]['img'])
```

nothing display in mobile and i see this message:

```
I/flutter (25006): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (25006): The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (25006): HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404,
I/flutter (25006): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload%5C0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
I/flutter (25006): 
I/flutter (25006): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (25006): #0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:90:9)
I/flutter (25006): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (25006): #1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
I/flutter (25006): #2      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
I/flutter (25006): #3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
I/flutter (25006): #4      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:325:84)
```

when i add this code

```
print(snapshot.data[index]['img']);
```

inside (itemBuilder in the ListView) this is the result:

```
Restarted application in 1,428ms.
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/mo11111
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload\500_F_216231494_oJFKyTVOUoiFMzvhhetAcSPktyZwhp7L.jpg
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\Capture.PNG
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\1_ir8j2Ag89QZFAKBZDZWEUw.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\download (1).jfif
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/mo11111
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload\500_F_216231494_oJFKyTVOUoiFMzvhhetAcSPktyZwhp7L.jpg
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\Capture.PNG
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\1_ir8j2Ag89QZFAKBZDZWEUw.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\download (1).jfif
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload%5C0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:90:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
#2      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
#3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/mo11111
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m11
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/m1
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/upload\500_F_216231494_oJFKyTVOUoiFMzvhhetAcSPktyZwhp7L.jpg
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\Capture.PNG
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\1_ir8j2Ag89QZFAKBZDZWEUw.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\download (1).jfif
I/flutter (21905): http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload\0157d41e-4db9-4d9a-9632-84c8a4cc15f1.png
D/ViewRootImpl@10bbcbe[MainActivity](21905): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@10bbcbe[MainActivity](21905): ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

EDIT.......
i notice a problem, because in browser i got this url for example:

```
http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload//1_ir8j2Ag89QZFAKBZDZWEUw.png
```

but in flutter it is like this:

```
http://192.168.43.106:3000/cupload%5C1_ir8j2Ag89QZFAKBZDZWEUw.png
```

there is the problem after (cupload)...
this is the code in node.js

```
const storage2 = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
   cb(null, 'cupload');
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
        cb(null, file.originalname);
         }
});
const filter2 = (req, file, cb)=>{
    if(file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "image/png"){
        cb(null, true)
    }else{
        cb(null, false);
    }
}
const cupload = multer({
    storage: storage2,
    filter: filter2
});
app.post('/cat', cupload.single('img'));
app.use('/cupload', express.static('cupload'));
```

Comment: Can you check inside your listView what you get for this. Just try to print and see, you get something `print(snapshot.data[index]['img'])`

Comment: yes, i said that, i get the url of images, and when i paste this url, it is work without problem,

Comment: Is there any chance that you could print the value of `snapshot.data` and update your question with the result?

Comment: i edited it now...

Answer (score 1):

please try using `r'snapshot.data[index]['img']'` as an Image URL